# How to convert an image to 16 Color Bitmap (like in MS Paint) using Pillow/PIL?

Tags: python, image-processing, bitmap, python-imaging-library

I've been reading all the documentation about 
[Pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/handbook/image-file-formats.html#bmp) and about colors and [type of bitmaps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms536393(v=vs.85).aspx).

The steps that I've been doing:

- Capturing a screenshot using print screen.
- Copying the screenshot into Microsoft Paint, and saving the picture
- Choosing the "16 Color Bitmap" in the save as dialog.

I'm trying to achieve the same result of MS Paint using pyscreenshot and PIL/Pillow using:

```
from pyscreenshot import ImageGrab
img = ImageGrab.grab()
img.convert(mode='P', colors=16).save("result.bmp")
```

But the result (the colors) we achieved using PIL doesn't look like the Paint results.

Any ideas why?

Thanks :)

UPDATE:
Adding the parameter palette=1 made the colors to change. (1=Adaptive, 0 = Web)
But it's still looks different then MS Paint's result. I'm wondering if the 16 colors of Paint are predefined or been chosen every time depend on the picture color?

Comment: Describe a bit more what ```But the result we achieved doesn't look like the paint "Save as".``` means. Color-quantization is lossy and dependent on perceptual theory (how are colors interpreted by our brain). This effects in tons of different algorithms to choose the color-palettes (clustering, neural-networks, ...).

Comment: The colors of the picture that was generated using Paint looks different from the colors of the same picture that was converted using PIL. Which algorithm does Paint use? How can I change the algorithm? Thanks.

Comment: Normal behaviour. But sadly i don't know which algorithm is in use and i doubt you can change it. Not sure, why you want to replicate it's behaviour. While paint might do it better than pillow (not sure), paint will be probably worse than the algorithms within imagemagick (if max-quality is your target). Another remark: *dithering* might also be in use (although i doubt it's default) and might improve results.

Comment: How about sharing the two images so they can be analysed?

Comment: Any Windows background picture which is not in solid color will do the work.

Comment: Some of us don't have/want Windows... which is why I asked for your MS-Paint and your PIL BMP files...